# Grails (Hibernate) Criteria query

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain class in my Grails app that looks like this:

```
class Event {
    Date date
}
```

I want to write a criteria query that selects events that occurred in a certain month of a certain year, any suggestions?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 2):

You could probably just use `between`:

```
def firstDayOfMonthInYear, lastDayOfMonthInYear;

/* set the two values using Calendar or some other mechanism */

Event.withCriteria {
    between('date', firstDayOfMonthInYear, lastDayOfMonthInYear)
}
```

I'm not certain of the inclusivity of `between` - you may need to adjust your start/end dates if it's not inclusive on both ends.